# Pointcut for a method that can take int/Integer

Tags: java, aop, pointcut

I am trying to cache an external service. To achieve that I am defining a pointcut.

```
public interface ExternalService
{
    public int getData(int);
}
```

Due do some concerns of cache manager not being able to figure out the difference among the overloaded methods, I need to define my pointcut with the **method argument type**.

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut id="cacheOperation"
        expression="execution(* com.ExternalSevice.getData(Integer)) || execution(* com.ExternalSevice.getData(int))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="cacheAdvise" pointcut-ref="cacheOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

If the external service changed the method to getData(Integer) tomorrow, I would want my caching to work just fine.

Question:
How do I define pointcut for a method argument - int or Integer?
And No I don't want

execution(* com.ExternalSevice.getData(..))

Comment: Why do you ask questions, creating work for others answering them, and then never give feedback or accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple. You just bind the parameter type to an advice parameter via `args()` and enjoy Java auto-unboxing:

**Driver application:**

I prepared this one in plain Java. It works with AspectJ, but the advice below should also work with Spring AOP.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public int getData(int i) {
        return i + i;
    }

    public Integer getMoreData(Integer i) {
        return i * i;
    }

    public String getSomethingElse(String string) {
        return string + " & " + string;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.getData(11);
        application.getMoreData(22);
        application.getSomethingElse("foo");
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class CacheOperationAspect {
    @Before("execution(* de.scrum_master..get*Data(*)) && args(number)")
    public void cacheOperation(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, int number) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + number);
    }
}
```

Instead of `cacheOperation(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, int number)` you could also use `cacheOperation(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Integer number)`, it depends on what you want to use in your aspect.

**Console log:**

```
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.getData(int)) -> 11
execution(Integer de.scrum_master.app.Application.getMoreData(Integer)) -> 22
```